# using row_number with no unique key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to get the record number from my select data.

At present I am aware of something like this:

```
SELECT max(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY aUniqueField)) FROM aTable
```

But this assumes that aUniqueField is a unique field and that it is the order I am returning it in.  Unfortunately, this is not the case for me. I need a way to 'affix' a row number that is independent of the values of any fields in my select statement.

Is there a way to do this?

These are my 2 tables:

[image]

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT                 
    FeatureName,       
    GF.[Enabled] AS [Enabled],       
    GroupId         
FROM       
    Feature F       
    JOIN GroupFeature GF ON GF.FeatureId = F.FeatureId          
WHERE   
    GroupId = 1 
OR 
    GroupId = 4 
OR  
    GroupId = 2 
Order By 
    Case GroupId  
        When 1 Then 1 
        When 4 Then 2 
        When 2 Then 3
```

By popular request :) I attach more info. I really should have done this from the beginning.

Data output as it stands:

```
Feature1, true, 1
Feature2, true, 4
Feature3, true, 4
Feature4, true, 4
Feature5, true, 2
```

What I would like is:

```
1,Feature1, true, 1
2,Feature2, true, 4
3,Feature3, true, 4
4,Feature4, true, 4
5,Feature5, true, 2
```

I have found if I remove the Order By/When clause then using the many suggestions here it works. When I reinstate it I get something like this:

```
1,Feature1, true, 1
3,Feature2, true, 4
4,Feature3, true, 4
5,Feature4, true, 4
2,Feature5, true, 2
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214544/how-to-increment-in-a-select-query

Comment: Why 42?  I have done so and I get this error: Windowed functions do not support integer indices as ORDER BY clause expressions.

Comment: @durbnpoisn HI, thanks for your time and that link. Unfortunately I have no primary key id I can use.

Comment: Do you need the same row number for each particular row every time you run the query?

Comment: How is this different from `select count(*) from aTable`?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' HI, thansk for posting. No I do not

Comment: To all, I strongly suspect that my Order By When Clause is causing the issue I had not realized this could change things. Sorry..

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hi, I understand the logic you are stating, I get this error thoough: Windowed functions do not support constants as ORDER BY clause expressions.

Comment: Although I'm glad you posted your tables and your current SQL statement, it's hard to see what `SELECT max(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY aUniqueField)) FROM aTable` has to do with it. You might want to make that clearer.

Comment: Unless you are sorting by a unique key (or combination) the order by is non-deterministic.   You example is not an order by independent of the values of any fields.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Hi, what i am trying to achieve is having a row number with the select statement.  This will give me a reference for each record without me having to use cursors or temp tables. The SELECT max(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY aUniqueField)) is just the syntax I found to use to do this but it does not work because I am not using a primary key anywhere

Comment: @Blam hi, yes I believe you.  Someone had asked for this data so I posted it. I was just being courteous to that poster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not fully clear to me what you are looking for
Affix a row number that is independent of the values of any fields is odd and you have correct answers that you state are are not working

```
DECLARE @map table(mapIn int primary key, mapout int)
insert into @map values (1,1), (4,2), (2,3)
select * from @map
SELECT FeatureName, GF.[Enabled] AS [Enabled], GroupId, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY map.mapout, GF.GroupFeatureID) RowNum         
  FROM Feature F       
  JOIN GroupFeature GF 
    ON GF.FeatureId = F.FeatureId  
  join @map map 
    on map.mapIn = GF.GroupId
 order by map.mapout, GF.GroupFeatureID
```

Comment: Hi, the answers given to me (and I thank everyone) failed because 1). I am not using a primary key and 2). for the answers that do not require a primary key the record number is skewed by my Order By/When clause..  thanks for ur sample code. It may be  I will have to use this after all. Many thanks :)

Comment: It is not clear what you want.  I suggest you post sample data and expected output.  Order by is non deterministic.  If the order by is not unique then you will not get repeatable results.

Comment: hi, thanks for your time. I have added to my original question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `ORDER BY` in the windowing function doesn't need to be unique, and if it's not you will still get a unique `ROW_NUMBER()` for each row:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (id int)

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES
    (1)
    ,(1)
    ,(1)
    ,(1)

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id), id
FROM @t
```

Returns:

```
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but I get these as the rownumbers: 1,2,1,1,1

Comment: @AndrewSimpson if you want help specific to your tables you need to share those tables and data with us.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (Select 1))
```

to get an independent row number

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NewID() to get the row number without reordering the data:

```
SELECT max(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NewID())) FROM aTable
```

Comment: Hi, did not work, I will edit my question with full tsql and tables